# "Post" button doesn't work if screen turns off

Tags: bug, android-app

If when I'm writing a comment, I stop typing for long enough and the screen turns off, then when it comes back, the "post" button doesn't work. Neither does the arrow on the left, so I can't discard.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: D6503
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (2769308465)

Comment: No repro on my LG G5.